# Deletinq record from database using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have problem with deleting records from database, using ajax and jquery. If i click to button nothing happens. there is my `css`:

```
<button class='delete_p' id_p='<?php echo $post_id; ?>'>x</button>"
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="delete_post.js"></script>
```

and there is `ajax` that i'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.delete_p').click(function(){
var del_id = $(this).attr('id_p');
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'delete_post.php',
  data:'delete_id='+del_id,
  });
 });
});
```

and there is `delete_post.php` that i'm using:

```
<?php
include 'esas/core/database/connect.php';
$id = $_POST['delete_id'];
$query = "DELETE FROM `status` WHERE `id` = '$id'";
?>
```

Comment: You are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Comment: You need to do a little more troubleshooting.  For example, does del_id even get set in your JS? (use an alert to find out)

Comment: @EdCottrell He is safe from SQL injections, because his SQL query is never executed.

Comment: @blex No, he's not. If a malicious user posts a value for `delete_id` like `1' OR '1' = '1` to `delete_post.php`, that's SQL injection. The fact that his AJAX call is currently busted doesn't change the fact that the back end is highly vulnerable.

Comment: I know i have sql injection. and i will fix it. ;)

Comment: but i put because of security `mysql_real_escape_string`

Answer (score 6):

`data` shouldn't be a string but a JavaScript object:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'delete_post.php',
  data: {
     delete_id: del_id
  }
});
```

Comment: @user3722203 additionally to this, try removing the single quotes around `$id` in you SQL query, because I guess they are integers, and not Strings. Oh, and in the question you posted, you set the $query String, but you never execute it, so nothing gets deleted.

Comment: Great! And yes, if you plan on making this public, take care of SQL injection.